# Are there uncountable groups which satisfy the minimal condition on subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

**Definition**

A group $G$ is said to satisfies the *minimal condition* on subgroups if every descending chain of subgroups stops after a finite number of steps.

I know this was an unsolved problem in past but I do not know if now it is solved. (Tarski groups are $2$-generated and hence countable.)

**Question**:  Is it true that every group satisfying the minimal condition on subgroups is countable?

Comment: Some information about these groups can be found here http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Artinian_group and in the references mentioned there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are uncountable artinian groups. The original reference is:

> A.Yu. Ol’shanskii, Geometry of defining relations in groups. Kluwer, 1991

Theorem 35.2 states that there are artinian groups of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

PS: In     [arXiv:1206.3639](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.3639v1.pdf) (Example 2.6) it is claimed that every artinian group is countable (on the other hand, the abstract and the introduction speak of countable artinian groups). A reference is given to Kurosh's classic text *The Theory of groups*, page 192. But I couldn't find it there ...

Comment: At page 192 of the Kurosh's text there is only said that a solvable group with minimal condition for subgroups is countable. So maybe is just a misprint. So you've answered to my first question. I'll do another question with a more complete statement as concern the second one. Thanks!